# How to restart a python script from inside itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, operating-system, undetected-chromedriver

I am making a bot of some kind and I need the bot to restart itself when certain conditions are met.

I currently have 1 working solution: os.system("py main.py")
The issue with this solution is that it creates a new python executable for every new instance and it is basically slowly killing the VM on which it is running.

I would need a solution that clears the previous process and starts all over again. I am working with chromedrivers if that helps.

I've tried various things already, basically the default google results. None of these seem to work:
os.execv(sys.executable, [os.path.basename(sys.executable)] + sys.argv)
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)

Comment: Please explain what does not work. Did you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer It just doesnt restart the program. In some cases it does restart but only once.

Comment: You could create a simple shell script or Python script which in a loop starts the actual program, waits until the program terminates and starts it again.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is if you run your program in while loop.
For example:

```
while True:
  # your code logic

  if restart_condition=True:
       continue
  # code logic

  # end of while loop
  if condition_for_end_of_program==True:
      break
```

Inside your while loop at the end you have to give one condition which specify that your code is come to its end.